# What is SSO & How to implement it in PHP?

Tags: php

Need a small help regarding Single Sign On. I want to implement SSO in my website but I don't have any idea of it also how to implement it in PHP.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You really don't need Single Sign On.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on   you could have done a bit of research first before coming here...

Comment: why negative? I went through wikipedia but its not clearing my concept thats why I came here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSO is Single Sign-On. It can be a large undertaking to implement it from scratch, but fortunately, you can just use a library like [Janrain Federate](http://janrain.com/products/federate/) and leverage that.

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that you probably don't need SSO and you might just need something like [Janrain Engage](http://janrain.com/products/engage/). I don't think it's SSO strictly speaking, but it is entirely possible that it will solve whatever problem you are trying to solve.